# git write-tree failed to write a tree

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I am trying to merge branch `feature` back to `master`. `master` is a dozen commits ahead of where `feature` branched off, `feature` consists of three commits that have no conflicts with anything done in `master` since. This should be a very simple merge.

If I were to do a rebase workflow, no issues whatsoever (filenames omitted):

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: first
Applying: second
Applying: third
$ git checkout master
$ git merge feature
Updating 5e42a1d..3642da3
Fast-forward
...
34 files changed, 575 insertions(+), 658 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 ...
create mode 100644 ...
copy ... (64%)
rename ... (64%)
delete mode 100644 DIR_1
create mode 100644 ...
create mode 100644 ...
delete mode 100644 DIR_2
rename ... => A (100%)
rename ... => B (100%)
rename ... => C (100%)
rename ... => D (100%)
rename ... => E (100%)
rename ... => F (100%)
rename ... => G (93%)
rename ... => H (94%)
rename ... => I (95%)
rename ... => J (92%)
rename ... => K (100%)
rename ... => L (100%)
rename ... => M (100%)
```

But, if I do a merge, which should equally have no issues:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge feature
Removing DIR_1
Removing DIR_2
A: unmerged (918a9f784e16a17792d47da2ea2623137c42b6b6)
B: unmerged (e7fe52f5c9ecc93ff25b66cc7c34a0ea511a809a)
C: unmerged (8e076d6459e36f7296a152c75b8c2d6a75abff18)
D: unmerged (93ae1467cfcb0dac26a7b503c49a72228cc35221)
E: unmerged (9014187a5c414024ec5e2deaf58ee2e3d6327dd6)
F: unmerged (109e70ec7786bdafd00a609f9f0b53a33b5f9989)
G: unmerged (c952cbf52ae282ee707b2d8a4166b53864b62bb7)
H: unmerged (0aa9792eae3bc7f84575c6f85662c494b53911fd)
I: unmerged (a6f19de4dbd21214e5716e6578d4c8591f5f6475)
J: unmerged (1812c7ec3701598203595ae411901626d3a3f2d9)
...
fatal: git write-tree failed to write a tree
```

The files `A`..`J` are the same files that were renamed to in the `rebase` output, and the same `DIR_1` and `DIR_2` that were marked as `delete mode`.

What does the error mean? What can cause my git merge to fail when the git rebase/merge succeeds cleanly? I am using git 1.7.0.4 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody runs into this in the future, it appears to have been a git bug. After upgrading to 1.8.3.1, I was able to perform a merge without any issues: no conflicts as expected, no "fatal: git write-tree failed to write a tree".